# Install binary version of old R packages?

Tags: r, binary, package-managers

I have an R script that was written by someone else that I need to run. This script depends on another library (written by yet another person) that generates an error when the script is run. This all began after I updated my desktop to the newest Mac OSX, and subsequently updated to the newest R (and newer versions of these dependencies). I'm unable to compile this older version due to some compilers errors (error: unsupported directive '.stabs'), so a binary version seems like the easier way to go than to start digging deep into OPC as a novice R programmer. Is there a way to force R to install older versions of a binary library like there is for package managers for languages like Python and Ruby?

Comment: check the checkpoint package and the related MRAN snapshot repositories.

Comment: I managed to work around it in another way, but I'll have to keep MRAN in mind, in case I am unable to grab an old copy of R from a similar machine.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing that worked fine was rsyncing my old installation from an old computer that had those libraries already installed. Both were Mac OSX, but the older computer was still on the previous OS and R was compatible and the scripts do run now.

Also, I did find that if you don't reinstall R after you upgrade OS X, the installation is still valid, you just have to recreate the sym links or add the binary to your PATH.